# I need a word for a Noun that has only one function or use

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests, nouns, technology

Let's say that an AI was created to toast bread. That is its only function, and only use. How would I describe such a thing in one word?
For instance: Like a _____, it executed its task.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does the word "single-function" not work?

Comment: Rather than "like a", you could just "this single-purpose tool executed its task".

Answer (score 0):

"*Like a dedicated appliance, …*" ?

> #### dedicated (adj.)
>
> "set apart and consecrated to a deity or to a sacred purpose by a solemn act or by religious ceremonies; devoted with earnest purpose, as to some person or end," c. 1600, usually of things, writings, property, etc., past-participle adjective from dedicate (v.).
>
> Of persons, "devoted to one's aims or vocation," attested clearly by 1936, but the sense shift can be felt in Lincoln's Gettysburg Address, which opens talking of "a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal," and a few lines later reintroduces the word personally: "It is for us, the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here, have, thus far, so nobly advanced. It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us ...."
>
> Of things, "**made to be available only for a particular purpose** or class of user," by 1969. Related: Dedicatedly.
>
> — [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=dedicated)

Answer (score 0):

On a cooking show called Serous Eats, Alton Brown calls such a kitchen utensil a **unitasker**. It is probably not in dictionaries. He uses the term derisively, as in “Do not buy a unitasker.”